# Elasticsearch 8.11.1 client instantiation fails

Tags: elasticsearch, client, instantiation

I instantiated an elasticsearch client using
elastic_client = Elasticsearch("http://localhost:9200") trying different numbers for ports such as `9200`, `13000` etc.

but I keep getting the error below
When I run `elastic_client.info()` i get following error:

```
elastic_transport.ConnectionError: Connection error caused by:  
ConnectionError(Connection error caused by: 
NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 
0x000001D19F5FBEC0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it))
```

I want the client to be on my local machine.
Can someone suggest how to address this issue? Thank you.